# Получить данные о группе facebook

Tags: python, api, facebook-api

Как получить, данные о группе в facebook ,к примеру: количество участников, или постов группы, без использования API и не нарушая правил facebook.

Comment: *... и не нарушая правил facebook* - никак

Comment: конечно, если Вы собственноручно будете делать подсчет, то правил не нарушите(наверное), но вряд ли Вы это ищите.

Comment: похожий вопрос [Получить число участников и фид с фейсбука без admin_group_access_token](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797036/23044)